# How to merge branch into master with accepting branch's changes

Tags: git

I have tried `rebase` and `merge` but both of them introduce conflicts which are very much for me to solve. My `master` branch is very old and I want to override it with files from `ready` branch.

I have the following branches:

-- master
-- ready

I want to merge `ready` into `master` so that `master` is just a clone of `ready`.

I do not want to solve conflicts, Actually, I want all files to be overridden not merged.

**NOTE:**

I have tried deleteing local `master` and renaming `ready` to `master` but I could not push it to my remote repo hosted at BitBucket, BitBucket does not allow the deletion of `master` branch. So I am stuck with `merge`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Kjuly has the best option.. go with it. FYI there is another alternative if you decide to keep the original version or the new version of the file.

For this, there is the --theirs and the --ours options on the git checkout command. The first option keeps the version of the file that you merged in, and the second option keeps the version before the merge operation was started.

```
git checkout --ours foo/bar.java
git add foo/bar.java
```

and

```
git checkout --theirs foo/bar.java
git add foo/bar.java
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to override the `master` branch, just force push your new cloned `master` from `ready`:

```
$ git checkout ready
$ git branch -D master      // delete old master
$ git checkout -b master    // create new master
$ git push -f origin master // force push the master br
```

---

**Suggestion**: Better to backup your old master before force override it in case you need to refer it in the feature.